# Error: C stack usage 133776899 is too close to the limit when using copy_to from sparklyr

Tags: r, dataframe, apache-spark, storage, sparklyr

I am trying to convert a `data.frame` to a `Spark DataFrame`:

```
library(sparklyr)

conf <- list()

conf$`sparklyr.cores.local` <- 4
conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "16G"
conf$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.9

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", 
                    config = conf)

load("./data/dfm_training.RData")
load("./data/training.RData")


df <- training[,c(1,2,3,18)]
df$TextLength <- nchar(df$txt)
df <- df[df$TextLength > 0,]

df.tokens.df <- cbind(nchar = df$TextLength, label = df$training2_CFT,
                  convert(dfm_training, to = "data.frame"))

## to spark
sdf <- copy_to(sc, df.tokens.df)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

`Error: C stack usage  133776899 is too close to the limit`

I have tried switching the number of cores and the number of memory used, but no changes.

Comment: What you're experiencing is that `copy_to` somehow performs a recursive call adding too many function calls to the stack. A previous [issue](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/298) on github from 2016 had a similar problem. `R` doesn't in general allow for mild depth recursion. It is a great question why this is happening with a simple call to `copy_to` however. It is not immediately apparent from your example.

Comment: I saw that issue,  however they do not solve it. My `df.tokens.df` has about 4gb, do you think that it might be related?

Comment: Honestly? No. I cannot myself fathom the reason in your specific example, but if you are familiar with debugging you could theoretically try calling `debug(sparklyr::copy_to)` and see if you can locate the specific call that causes your stack-overflow. If it is different from the issue, I'd suggest opening a new issue on their github, and if you find a solution post and answer both here and in their github.